# Extending Restlet 2.3 ClientInfo

Tags: restlet, restlet-2.0

Is it possible to extend `org.restlet.data.ClientInfo`? I need a convenient way of adding a `List<String> permissions` to complement the existing `List<Role> roles`. In a perfect world I would be able to add `List<Permission> permissions` but the former is perfectly acceptable.

I need to be able to get this from the request: `org.restlet.resource.Resource.getRequest().getClientInfo().getPermissions()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that it's possible to add something within the class `ClientInfo` since it's a class that is managed by the Restlet engine. You can't subclass it to add a field `permissions` (you don't have the hand on the client info instantiation).

That said, you can leverage the context attributes. I mean that you can fill within your `Enroler` implementation an attribute `permissions` for the request, as described below:

```
public class MyEnroler implements Enroler {
    private Application application;

    public MyEnroler(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    public void enrole(ClientInfo clientInfo) {
        // Roles
        Role role = new Role(application, "roleId",
                    "Role name");
        clientInfo.getRoles().add(role);

        // Permissions
        Request request = Request.getCurrent();
        List<Permission> permissions = new ArrayList<Permission>();
        request.getAttributes().put("permissions", permissions);

        Permission permission = (...)
        permissions.add(permission);
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry